# Trigonometry from two graphs

Tags: trigonometry

My problem is that i have an image or rectangle which has line inside it which is rigid it will not move. I also have a graph with the same line but may be slightly bigger and may have a slightly different gradient but not by much, so scaling is needed to grow or shrink the rectangle. Once this is done i will need to rotate the image and match it to the line on the graph. And once that is done then i have to work out points A,B,C and D.

Please see these images for further clarification:

[Graph 1 shows line Graph 2 shows end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap1FP.jpg)

[Image to be rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEqir.jpg)

I have had some thoughts on how to do the scaling the (easy bit):

Using Pythagoras therom to find the length of line in Graph 1 and find the length in the image/rectangle these lengths will equal each other thus i can get a ratio.

**Any** help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what i understand is that  you need to scale the line **segment** by some scale factor and rotate it by some angle, right ?

Comment: correct that is precisely it.

Comment: Then use vectors and matrices.

Comment: could you expand please?

Comment: Are you aware of rotation and scale matrices ?

Comment: sorry no i am not

Comment: rotation matrix :- $$\begin {bmatrix} \cos \theta &  -\sin \theta & \\ \sin \theta &  \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}$$ 
scale matrix :- $$\begin {bmatrix} \mathsf{x- amount} &  0 & \\ 0 & \mathsf{y- amount} \end{bmatrix}$$ 
Now you only need to get the vectors pointing the end points of the line segment and then just need to do simple vector matrix multiplication. There are other more basic ways but this is the most easy to implement in computer programs.

Comment: oh ok i will read up on it and give it a try...